# Control Inline Block Element Size on Mobile in Gmail

Tags: html, css, email

I'm trying to setup some links in an email and I'm having trouble getting them to display correctly.

```
<p style="display: block; text-align: center;font-size: 20px;line-height:40px;width: 85%; margin: 0 auto;font-weight:300;margin-top:20px;">
<a style="width: 45%; display: inline-block; background-color: #ebebeb; color: #333; text-decoration: none; margin: 0 10px; border-top:0; border-right: 1px; border-bottom: 1px; border-left: 0; border-color: #b8b8b8; border-style:solid;" href="http://example.com"">Link One</a>
<a style="width: 45%; display: inline-block; background-color: #ebebeb; color: #333; text-decoration: none; margin: 10px; border-top:0; border-right: 1px; border-bottom: 1px; border-left: 0; border-color: #b8b8b8; border-style:solid;" href="http://example.com" >Link Two</a>
</p>
```

They appear fine on desktop (side by side). On mobile I'd like them to stack but, as expected, they only take up 45% of the screen which is too small.

Since I can't reliably use media queries because of Gmail, is there any way to make them stack and appear at a reasonable width on mobile?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `min-width` to your anchor's, and since you re-style the `p`, use a `div` instead.

```
<div style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;line-height:40px;width: 85%; margin: 0 auto;font-weight:300;margin-top:20px;">
    <a style="min-width: 300px; width: 45%; display: inline-block; background-color: #ebebeb; color: #333; text-decoration: none; margin: 0 10px; border-top:0; border-right: 1px; border-bottom: 1px; border-left: 0; border-color: #b8b8b8; border-style:solid;" href="http://example.com"">Link One</a>
    <a style="min-width: 300px; width: 45%; display: inline-block; background-color: #ebebeb; color: #333; text-decoration: none; margin: 10px; border-top:0; border-right: 1px; border-bottom: 1px; border-left: 0; border-color: #b8b8b8; border-style:solid;" href="http://example.com" >Link Two</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bring your code back to the past using tables. This technique is only reliable if it's just for an email.

```
<table width="500px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="50%"><a href="http://example.com">Link one</a></td>
      <td width="50%"><a href="http://example.com">Link two</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```